# iOS not deleting app data after app deletion

Tags: iphone, ios, memory

I am using iOS 16.5.1. My signal app is about 8G. I have deleted the app and when I reinstall it, it doesn’t go through authentication again and brings up all my previous chats. I check in the settings and iOS has about 16G of System Data not reclaiming the 8G of memory.

I have tried doing this multiple times; restarted my device as well as concluded soft resets.

When I try this on a different device, iOS deletes the data just fine and app has a fresh reinstall. Any help would be great. Thanks.